# MySQLdb error when using cursor.execute()

Tags: python, mysql

I am using python and specifically MySQLdb to fill a database, although a code that was working until recently is throwing up an error after moving servers at work:

The code is:

```
cursor.execute("""SELECT Entry, A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P FROM evaluation""")

result = cursor.fetchall()

for record in result:
    codeno=int(str(record[15]))
    status, progress, reprocessing = RepStatus_new.get_status(code=codeno, proj_tag=str(record[16]),cache_dir="cache", prod_type="g1")
    cursor.execute("""UPDATE evaluation SET M=%s WHERE A LIKE %s""",(progress, int(str(record[15]))))
```

and the error that comes up is:

```
File "mySQLtest.py", line 165, in <module>
    cursor.execute("""UPDATE evaluation SET M=%s WHERE A LIKE %s""",(progress, int(str(record[15]))))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.5/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 166, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.5/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 35, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorclass, errorvalue
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1205, 'Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction')
```

I am not sure where this is going wrong, as I said this code worked until recently.  If anyone has any suggestions they would be much appreciated! (I replaced variables with letters to aid read-ability!)

The database is connecting correctly, as I can output the "result" after cursor.fetchall()

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a quick fix, but changing `innodb_lock_wait_timeout` might temporarily defer the "Lock wait timeout exceeded" issue. See [doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_lock_wait_timeout).

Any chance the MySQL version, engine(s), or config's changed when you "moved servers"?

Reading the results of `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` would alert you to any recent locking issues.

Last time I seen this when I "moved servers", it was because of conflicting/duplicate scripts/crons trying to hit the same tables.

At any rate, you might want to push this over to serverfault.